# Android - resize/scale image through dragging and dropping

Tags: java, android, image

In Android, is there any built-in way for resizing an image through selecting it, and then dragging the corners/sides to the desired dimensions?

To illustrate what I wish to achieve:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is cropping image.

you can achieve that with default android Crop functionality:

```
private void performCrop(Uri picUri) {
try {

    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    // indicate image type and Uri
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
    // set crop properties
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    // indicate aspect of desired crop
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    // indicate output X and Y
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 128);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 128);
    // retrieve data on return
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
}
// respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    // display an error message
    String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
}
```

Constant declare:

```
 final int PIC_CROP = 1;
```

override onActivity result method in your activity, writ following code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PIC_CROP) {
        if (data != null) {
            // get the returned data
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            // get the cropped bitmap
            Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");

            imgView.setImageBitmap(selectedBitmap);
        }
    }

}
```